# XSLT1.0 Looping over self-referenced data

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got a static list of countries in xsl that I'd like to be able to call with a preselected value. To do this requires iterating over each node and doing a simple check (prefereably while keeping countries self-contained in the same file). However, performing a <xsl:copy-of> works, but a <xsl:for-each> on the same expression does not - what's going on? Is this possible?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:isoCountry="isoCountry:country">
  <isoCountry:country>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="AU">Australia</option>
      <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
      <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
      <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
      <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
  </isoCountry:country>

  <xsl:template name="CountrySelect">
    <select>

      <option> <!-- correct number of nodes, good -->
        <xsl:value-of select="count(document('')/*/isoCountry:menu/menu/*)"/>
      </option> 

      <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/isoCountry:country/option"/> <!-- this works -->

      <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/isoCountry:country/option"> <!-- this does not -->
        <option><xsl:value-of select="."/></option>
      </xsl:for-each>

    </select>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want the `for-each` to do. It outputs the text value of each `country/option` wrapped in an `option` element. If you want a copy of the `option` use  `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>`.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, the intent is to do something like
<option value="@value">
<xsl:attribute> <!-- if param = selected, add a selected attribute--> </attribute>
<xsl:value-of select="."/></option>

Comment: What does your desired output look like(add it to your question)?

Comment: How is your input document structured? It might be cleaner to use matching to generate the output (as opposed to calling a named template).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example calling your `CountrySelect` template with a `param` to generate a `selected` attribute when the `value` attribute is matched.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
        version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:isoCountry="isoCountry:country"
        exclude-result-prefixes="isoCountry">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <isoCountry:country>
        <option value=""/>
        <option value="AU">Australia</option>
        <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
        <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
        <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    </isoCountry:country>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <form>
            <xsl:call-template name="CountrySelect">
                <xsl:with-param name="selected">AU</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </form>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="CountrySelect">
        <xsl:param name="selected"/>
        <select>
            <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/isoCountry:country/option">
                <xsl:element name="{name()}"> <!-- could just be name="option" -->
                    <xsl:if test="$selected=@value">
                        <xsl:attribute name="selected">true</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </select>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```